# How do you train a pytorch model with multiple outputs

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

I am trying to train a model with the following data[image]

The image is the input and 14 features must be predicted.
Could I please know how to go about training such a model?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

These are not really features as far as I am concerned. These are classes and if I got it correctly, your images sometimes belong to more than one classes.

This is a very broad question but I think [here](https://learnopencv.com/multi-label-image-classification-with-pytorch-image-tagging/) might be a good start to learn more about **multi-label image classification**.

Note that your model should not be much different than an image classification model that is used for cifar10 challenge, for example. But you need to structure your data and choose your loss function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you very much. I shall look into it

Comment: Could I please know how to structure the data?